# My pygame window displays a black screen everytime I run my project

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I wrote this code below and just get a black screen on my pygame window everytime I run my project on pycharm

I copied this code through a tutorial step by step and checked it but the teacher didn’t seem to have this problem when running the code

```
import pygame
width = 500
height = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Client")

clientNumber = 0

class Player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = (x, y, width, height)
        self.vel = 3

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)

    def move(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= self.vel

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += self.vel

        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)



def redrawWindow(win, player):
    win.fill((255, 255, 255))
    player.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    run = True
    p = Player(50, 50, 100, 100, (0, 255, 0))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
    p.move()
    redrawWindow(win, p)

main()
```

Comment: Your issue is your indentation, the two lines `p.move()` and `redrawWindow(win, p)` should be indented so they are in your while loop

Comment: thank you so much man! I’ve been tryna figure out what was wrong for a while and got very discouraged to code. Bless you bro

Answer (score 0):

Press tab before `p.move()` and `redrawWindow(win, p)` so they look like this

```
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
    p.move()
    redrawWindow(win, p)
```

They should be indented under while loop.